# How to show and hide marker on Google map when clicked multi Button

Tags: android, json, dictionary

I'm using 3 URL to load data JSON and with 3 Buttons. I wish When I click button 'All', it will show all marker, or click remaining button, is will show corresponding marker(includes: station petro and Rescue)

this is my activity:

```
Button btnAll, btnPetro, btnRescue;

public void displaySelectedMarkers(View view) {

    btnAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAll);
    btnPetro = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPetro);
    btnRescue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRescue);

    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (view.equals(btnAll)) {
                Log.d("Get All marker ", "Button get All was clicked ");
                get_all_marker_by_area();
            }
            else if (view.equals(btnPetro)) {
                Log.d("Get All marker petro ", "Button get All petro was clicked ");
                get_all_marker_by_petro();
            }
            else if (view.equals(btnRescue)) {
                Log.d("Get All marker Rescue", "Button get All Rescue was clicked ");
                get_all_marker_by_rescue();
            }
            else {
                // get_all_marker_by_area();       // call and get all marker by area
            }
        }
    };

    btnPetro.setOnClickListener(listener);
    btnRescue.setOnClickListener(listener);
}
```

When I click 'All' or 'Petro' or 'Rescue' button, it seem not show any marker from json on Google Map.

How to filter marker on Google when click Button ? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to hide markers:

```
markerN.setVisible(false);
```

So you can call a loop if you have an `ArrayList` or `List` of your markers and toggle their visibility using a flag.

Comment: Hi @sinapda: thank for your idea, maybe I need create more loop for marker in displaySelectedMarkers method

Comment: I want to ask more. With 3 URL, I should create one method or three method

Comment: You can create one method with an additional argument for the kind of markers that need to be displayed. Like `showMarkers(int TYPE)`